# how frequently pattern attribute will be validating the text entered in html input

Tags: html, regex, onchange, keyup

when i am doing a input field validation using pattern , how frequently the value will be validated . i would like to know whether it will validate on (keyup) or (change)

for ex:

```
<input type="email" [(ngModel)]="emailAddress" name="emailAddress" data-toggle="tooltip"
                    title="{{emailAddress}}" #email="ngModel" multiple
                    pattern="^(([a-zA-Z0-9_,.]*@*\w+([-+.']\w+)*\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*)*([' '])*)*$"
                    class="form-control" />
```

i would like to know whether the text i  enter will be validated on each keystroke ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern attribute is checked only upon submission the form or when you press enter on the `input` tag, so only on the `enter` key's stroke you might say.

If you **want** it to be validated on every `keypress`, `keyup` or `onchange`, you can set the corresponding attribute to validate the input like so:

```
<input keyup="validate(this)" />

...

<script>
function validate(x)
{
    regex = /[a-zA-Z0-9]+/;
    window.alert(x.value.match(regex) == null);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Robo Mop,,,i just want to know its behavior , i dont want to validate on change/each keystroke . so only , on submission of the form / enter key the value will be validated . thanks for the response

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly your issue, you are trying to check the value entered "real time".

In the case, you could use `input` event to get value changed.

```js
// Add error message element after input.
$('#input_email').after('<span class="error-message">Please write your message error here!</span>')

$('#input_email').on('input', function (evt) {
  var $regex=/^(([a-zA-Z0-9_,.]*@*\w+([-+.']\w+)*\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*)*([' '])*)*$/;
  var value = evt.target.value;
  if (value.length === 0) {
    evt.target.className = ''
    return
  }
  
  var result = value.match($regex);
  
  if (result) {
    evt.target.className = 'valid'
  } else {
    evt.target.className = 'invalid'
  }
})
```

```css
input.invalid + .error-message {
  display: initial;
}

.error-message {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="input_email" type="email" [(ngModel)]="emailAddress" name="emailAddress" data-toggle="tooltip"
                    title="{{emailAddress}}" #email="ngModel" multiple
                    pattern="^(([a-zA-Z0-9_,.]*@*\w+([-+.']\w+)*\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*)*([' '])*)*$"
                    class="form-control" />
```

Comment: i dont want to check the value on realtime , i just want to know when the pattern will be validated against the value (like on entering / on submit) @Robo Mop answered my question. thanks for your reply as well